# xmonad could not find module `XMonad': broken package

Tags: haskell, ghc, xmonad

Hi my Xmonad has been working perfectly until few days ago, then I think I installed something with Synaptic and then started  to complain about Xmonad.Config.Gnome 
here it is my xmonad.hs

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome


myManageHook = composeAll [
            (className =? "Pidgin" <&&> title =? "Buddy List") --> doFloat
           , (className =? "Gnome-panel" <&&> title =? "Run Application") --> doFloat
           -- , (className =? "XEyes") --> doShift "7"
           ]


main = xmonad $ gnomeConfig {
         modMask = mod4Mask
       , manageHook = myManageHook <+> manageHook gnomeConfig
       }
```

When I compile I get this:

```
ghc --make "xmonad.hs" (nella cartella: /home/giuseppe/.xmonad)
xmonad.hs:2:7:
Could not find module `XMonad.Config.Gnome':
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Compilazione fallita.

using `ghc-pkg list` I get:

```
WARNING: there are broken packages.  Run 'ghc-pkg check' for more details.
/var/lib/ghc-6.12.1/package.conf.d
Cabal-1.8.0.2
X11-1.5.0.0
X11-xft-0.3
array-0.3.0.0
base-3.0.3.2
base-4.2.0.0
bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
bytestring-0.9.1.5
containers-0.3.0.0
directory-1.0.1.0
dph-base-0.4.0
dph-par-0.4.0
dph-prim-interface-0.4.0
dph-prim-par-0.4.0
dph-prim-seq-0.4.0
dph-seq-0.4.0
extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.1
filepath-1.1.0.3
ghc-6.12.1
ghc-binary-0.5.0.2
ghc-prim-0.2.0.0
haskell98-1.0.1.1
hpc-0.5.0.4
integer-gmp-0.2.0.0
mtl-1.1.0.2
old-locale-1.0.0.2
old-time-1.0.0.3
pretty-1.0.1.1
process-1.0.1.2
random-1.0.0.2
rts-1.0
syb-0.1.0.2
template-haskell-2.4.0.0
time-1.1.4
unix-2.4.0.0
utf8-string-0.3.4
xmonad-0.9.1
/home/giuseppe/.ghc/i386-linux-6.12.1/package.conf.d
HTTP-4000.0.9
MonadCatchIO-mtl-0.3.0.1
binary-0.5.0.2
binary-shared-0.8.1
deepseq-1.1.0.0
ghc-mtl-1.0.1.0
ghc-paths-0.1.0.8
hslogger-1.0.12
libmpd-0.5.0
network-2.2.1.8
parsec-2.1.0.1
process-leksah-1.0.1.3
regex-base-0.93.2
regex-tdfa-1.1.4
split-0.1.2.1
xhtml-3000.2.0.1
xmonad-0.9.1
xmonad-contrib-0.9.1
zlib-0.5.2.0
```

and ghc-pkg:

```
There are problems in package xmonad-contrib-0.9.1:
dependency "unix-2.4.0.0-7d42d72856fae71324453279e546294e" doesn't exist
There are problems in package xmonad-0.9.1:
dependency "unix-2.4.0.0-7d42d72856fae71324453279e546294e" doesn't exist

The following packages are broken, either because they have a problem
listed above, or because they depend on a broken package.
xmonad-contrib-0.9.1
xmonad-0.9.1
```

So it looks like two packages are broken. What is the best way to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The errors displayed by ghc-pkg show that somehow the `unix-2.4.0.0` package has been changed since you installed xmonad.

Just re-install xmonad and xmonad-contrib and this problem should be fixed.  If you installed them with cabal-install (i.e. by running `cabal install xmonad`), then just re-run that command.  If you installed them with Synaptic or a similar tool, then I suspect that re-installing with Synaptic will break whatever you installed recently that broke xmonad.  You might want to look through open bugs to see if this is a known problem because it sounds like a broken package.  If this is the case, your best option to get something working quickly might be to uninstall xmonad and xmonad-contrib, then re-install them using cabal-install.